# How do I use CastleWindsor to resolve an SqlWorkflowInstanceStore

Tags: c#, castle-windsor

I have a SqlWorkflowInstanceStore object that I want to use CastleWindsor to create for me.
A SqlWorkflowInstanceStore takes a constructor parameter of a connection string.
My connection string is in my app.config.

Without using CastleWindsor this works:

```
InstanceStore persistanceStoreX = new SqlWorkflowInstanceStore(ConfigManager.Instance.GetSQLConnectionString());
```

I've tried these snippets with CastleWindsor:

```
WindsorContainer.Register(Component.For<InstanceStore>().ImplementedBy<SqlWorkflowInstanceStore>().DependsOn(Property.ForKey("InstanceStore").Eq(ConfigManager.Instance.GetSQLConnectionString())));
```

and

```
var connString = ConfigManager.Instance.GetSQLConnectionString();
WindsorContainer.Register(Component.For<InstanceStore>().ImplementedBy<SqlWorkflowInstanceStore>().DependsOn(new { InstanceStore = connString }));
```

When resolved with this:

```
_persistanceStore = _iodManager.WindsorContainer.Resolve<InstanceStore>();
```

I get a valid container but it has a null ConnectionString field.

What is the correct way to initialize the SqlWorkflowInstanceStore ?

InstenceStore is the Abstract class base for SqlWorkflowInstanceStore
ConfigManager.Instance.GetSQLConnectionString() is a singleton instance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From looking at [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee248437.aspx), it appears the ctor parameter for `SqlWorkflowInstanceStore` takes a parameter called `connectionString` so I think your registration code should be:

```
WindsorContainer.Register(Component.For<InstanceStore>().ImplementedBy<SqlWorkflowInstanceStore>().DependsOn(Property.ForKey("connectionString").Eq(ConfigManager.Instance.GetSQLConnectionString())));
```

Comment: Ta.  That works.  I was using the parameter name from the Abstract class rather than from the concrete ( I think)